# Проблема с запросами с сервера node Js

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь сделать свой пакет telegram Бота для удобства написания его через Node JS.

Если увидите ошибки в моем коде, пожалуйста, сообщите сразу, так как это мой первый большой ООП проект и я ток учусь)

После того как я прочитал что библиотека request устарела, я задался вопросом как мне делать запросы на сайт с новыми фичами.

Так же, возникла проблема с загрузкой mp3 файла с сервера "Последние 4 строки кода", сохраненный файл не удается запустить. Как можно корректно скачать файл на сервер?

````
"use strict"
let request = require("request-promise");


class TelegramAPI {
    constructor(token) {
        this.token = token;
        this.lastUpdateId = undefined;
    }

    buildURL(method) {
        let url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${this.token}/${method}`;
        return url;
    }


    getMe() {

    }
    getUpdate() {
        let data = {
            uri: this.buildURL("getUpdates"),
            body: {
                offset: this.lastUpdateId
            },
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true
        }
        request(data).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    on(type, callBack) {
        let data = {
            uri: this.buildURL("getUpdates"),
            body: {
                offset: this.lastUpdateId
            },
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true
        }
        request(data).then((request) => {
            let value = request.result;
            if (value[0]) {
                this.lastUpdateId = ++value[value.length - 1].update_id;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                if (!value[i].edited_message && value[i].message.text && type === "message") {
                    callBack(value[i].message);
                } else if (value[i].edited_message && type === "editMessage") {
                    callBack(value[i].edited_message);
                } else if (!value[i].edited_message && value[i].message.poll && type === "poll") {
                    callBack(value[i].message);
                }
            }
            setTimeout(() => { this.on(type, callBack) }, 1000);
        })
    }

    sendMessage(id, text, settings = { "pagePreview": false, "disNotification": false, "replyMessageId": null }) {

        let url = this.buildURL("sendMessage");


        let data = {
            uri: url,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                "chat_id": id,
                "text": text,
                "disable_web_page_preview": settings.pagePreview || false,
                "disable_notification": settings.disNotification || false,
                "reply_to_message_id": settings.replyMessageId
            },
            json: true
        }
        request(data).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    sendAudio(id, file, settings = { performer: "Исполнитель не указан", title: "Неизвестное название" }) {

        let url = this.buildURL("sendAudio");

        let data = {
            uri: url,
            body: {
                "chat_id": id,
                "audio": file,
                "performer": settings.performer,
                "title": settings.title
            },
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true

        }
    }
}


let file = fs.createWriteStream("music.mp3");

request("https://zaycev.net/musicset/dl/8ef61c696365a43c99831a8e37a128a5/4362299.json").then(response => {
    file.write(response);
    file.end();
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как можно корректно скачать файл на сервер?

Сохранить файл по заданному `URL` можно таким способом:

(*данный способ работает с [перенаправлением](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), прогресс-индикатором и автоматическим вычислением имени загружаемого файла*)

```js
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// Пытается вычислить имя файла по заданному URL
function getFilenameFromLink(link) {
    const filename = link.replace(/\?.*$/,'').match(/[^\/]+$/);
    return Array.isArray(filename) ? filename.shift() : filename;
}

// Пытается вычислить имя файла из хедера или URL
function getFilename(headers, url) {
    let filename = getFilenameFromLink(url);
    let ext = '';
    let match;

    if (headers.hasOwnProperty('content-disposition')) {
        if (match = /filename\*?=(\S+)/i.exec(headers['content-disposition'])) {
            const [ matchedFullText, fname ] = match;
            const encoding = fname.slice(0,5).toLowerCase();
    
            if (encoding == "utf-8") {
                filename = decodeURIComponent(fname.slice(7));
            } else if (encoding == "utf8'") {
                filename = decodeURIComponent(fname.slice(6));
            } else {
                filename = fname.replace(/[^\w\-\.]/g, '');
            }
        }
    }

    if (headers.hasOwnProperty('content-type')) {
        ext = headers['content-type'].match(/[^\/]+$/);
        if (Array.isArray(ext)) {
            ext = ext.shift();
        }

        if (filename.length && !/\.\w+$/.test(filename)) {
            filename += `.${ext}`;
        }
    }

    return filename;
}

function downloadFile(url, dirname, callback) {
    const httpModule = url.substr(0, 6) == 'https:' ? https : http;
    const request = httpModule.get(url, res => {
        // Перенаправление
        if (res.statusCode === 302) {
            process.stdout.write(`${res.statusCode} GET "${url}"\n`);

            // запускаем после окончания текущей операции Event Loop
            process.nextTick(downloadFile, res.headers.location, dirname, callback);
        }

        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            process.stdout.write(`${res.statusCode} GET "${url}"`);

            let filename = getFilename(res.headers, url);

            if (filename.length > 255) {
                // Взять последние 30 символов из имени файла
                filename = filename.slice(-30);
            }

            if (!filename.length) {
                filename = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\D/g,'');
            }

            // инициализируем прогресс
            downloadFile.progress = {
                delta: 0,
                percents: 0,
                peak: res.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-length') 
                    ? +res.headers['content-length'] : 0
            };

            if (!downloadFile.hasOwnProperty('stream')) {
                // Открываем поток для записи
                downloadFile.stream = fs.createWriteStream(`${dirname}/${filename}`, { autoClose: true });

                // Сохраняем файл
                res.pipe(downloadFile.stream);
            }

            res.on('data', chunk => {
                downloadFile.progress.delta += chunk.length;
                const percents = Math.ceil((downloadFile.progress.delta * 100) / downloadFile.progress.peak);

                if (downloadFile.progress.percents != percents) {
                    downloadFile.progress.percents = percents;
                    const size = calculate(downloadFile.progress.delta);
                    process.stdout.write(`\x1B[s (~${size}) ${percents}%\x1B[u`);
                }
            });

            // Закрываем поток, очищаем временные данные
            res.on('end', function () {
                const size = calculate(downloadFile.progress.delta);
                process.stdout.write(` (~${size}) ${downloadFile.progress.percents}%\n`);
                cleanupAfterDownloadFile();
                // Согласно контракту первым аргументом передаем ошибку, вторым - данные
                callback(null, filename);
            });
        }
    });

    request.on('error', err => {
        // Закрываем поток, очищаем временные данные, передаем ошибку
        cleanupAfterDownloadFile();
        // Согласно контракту первым аргументом передаем ошибку, вторым - данные
        callback(err, null);
    });

    // (!) это важно
    request.end();
}

function calculate(bytes) {
    // сложно сказать почему не 1024^2, где-то читал, что потоки 
    // считаются не по 1024 а по 1000.
    // когда я использую константу в 1024, размер файла в LINUX
    // отличается от показателей индикатора
    return bytes < 1000000 
        ? (bytes / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'Kb'
        : (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(1) + 'Mb'
    ;
}

function cleanupAfterDownloadFile() {
    if (downloadFile.hasOwnProperty('stream')) {
        downloadFile.stream.close();
        delete downloadFile.stream;
    }
}

// Promise обертка
function downloadFileAsync(url, dirname) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        downloadFile(url, dirname, function (err, filename) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(filename);
        });
    });
}

// пакетная загрузка
function downloadBatch(dirname, list=[]) {
    if (list.length) {
        downloadFile(list.shift(), dirname, function(err, filename) {
            // err ? console.error(err)
            //     : console.log('Saved to: %s/%s', dirname, filename)
            // ;
            err && console.error(err);

            // дожидаемся очереди и снова пытаемся скачать файл
            setImmediate(downloadBatch, dirname, list);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('FINISH!');
    }
}
```

Применение:

Вариант с использованием `callback-метода`

```js
const url = 'https://...';
const dirname = '.';

downloadFile(url, dirname, function (err, filename) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Saved to: %s/%s', dirname, filename);
});
```

Вариант с использованием `Promise`

```js
function processPromise(filename) {
    filename && console.log('Saved to: %s/%s', dirname, filename);

    if (files.length) {
        return downloadFileAsync(files.shift(), dirname);
    }
}

const dirname = '.';
const urls = [
    'https://...',
    'https://...',
    'https://...'
];

Promise.resolve()
    .then(processPromise)
    .then(processPromise)
    .then(processPromise)
    .catch(console.error)
;

// Или так:

try {
    const filename = await downloadFileAsync('https://...', dirname);
    filename && console.log('Saved to: %s/%s', dirname, filename);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Пакетная загрузка

```js
const dirname = '.';
const list = Array.from(['','','','',''], () => 'https://picsum.photos/1024/768');

downloadBatch(dirname, list);
```

Затронутые термины: [Контрактное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), [Http-статусы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), [Перенаправление](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Disposition), [rfc6266](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.5), [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Event Loop](https://medium.com/devschacht/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick-18579cd122e0)